# Seed method keeps generating duplicate data using AddOrUpdata and DropCreateAlways (Code First, EF)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem when seeding my database using a code first approach in EF. I find this odd since I'm using the AddOrUpdate method. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MovieModel
{
    public class MovieContext : DbContext
    {
        public MovieContext() : base("name=MovieContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MovieContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MovieContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also tried it using DropCreateDatabaseAlways but it never drops it. I also adapted my model and it generated a new table for the new class, but the old data still resided and duplicate data was added again.

And the seed method and class:

```
namespace MovieModel.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MovieModel.MovieContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(MovieModel.MovieContext context)
        {
            var genres = new List<Genre>
            {
                new Genre{Description = "Action"},
                new Genre{Description = "Thriller"},
                new Genre{Description = "Fantasy"},
                new Genre{Description = "Horror"},
                new Genre{Description = "Science Fiction"}
            };

            genres.ForEach(g => context.Genres.AddOrUpdate(g));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't made an application yet, thus far I've runned it using Package Manager Console using the Update-Database command. Migrations are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the key in the AddOrUpdate:

```
genres.ForEach(g => context.Genres.AddOrUpdate(g => g.Description, g));
```

You could also just check if they already exist:

```
if (!context.Genres.Any())
{
    // Move your seed code here
}
```

Comment: That solution works if you use another letter instead, e.g: genres.ForEach(g => context.Genres.AddOrUpdate(u => u.Description, g)); Right now I've added a list of movies when I create a Genre. This works. When I create a movie I also create a director, however when I create the same director, for example Silvester Stallone and the movies Expandables I and II, good old Sly shows up twice in the Database. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Yeah, you need to make sure you attach the director to the context before saving the movie. See attaching an existing entity to the context here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx